# Is my implementation considered Insertion sort?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, insertion

```
function insertionSort(ul){
    for(var i =0; i< ul.length; i++){
        for(var j = i-1; j<ul.length; j++){
            if(ul[j] > ul[j+1]){
            [ul[j],ul[j+1]] = [ul[j+1], ul[j]]
            }
        }

    }
    return ul
}

var ul = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4];  
console.log(insertionSort(ul));
```

^Is my implmentation considered Insertion sort, or is it Bubble sort?

Answer (score 0):

With insertion sort, the sorting process is done **while** filling the array. Thus, **your code is not an insertion sort**: it starts with an array already filled.

You do not specify the programming language, but the very first test your code does looks really weird: `if (ul[-1] > ul[0]) ...` (tested the first time the runtime enters the nested loops). Therefore, **this may not be a bubble sort**, either. Your implementation should be improved.